# Lightbox usage in html

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox, lightbox2

I've used lightbox but i have a problem.

That's normally lightbox structure:

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">image #1</a>
```

But my structure:

```
<a href="#" ><img src="images/product_1.jpg" rel="lightbox"width="220" height="208" /></a>
```

So, when add `rel="lightbox"` after `a href="#"` open pop-up but not show large image. When add in `img src` lightbox effect don't working.

I don't change my html structure, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption" >
  <img src="images/product_1.jpg" width="220" height="208" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
<a class="thumbnailhover" rel="lightbox" href="works1/images/index6.jpg">
  <img src="works1/thumbnails/index6.jpg" width="150" height="135"  border="0" /> 
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use fancybox? It is much smaller and easier to use. It is also very widely documented with examples.

Here's the link:     http://fancybox.net/howto